Unity2D Webview package for WebGL?
I need to open a webpage by url I get in api response. Here I am showing three screens, one by one after a time difference, I need to show the content of the webpage in Unity ImageView.
I have tried https://github.com/gree/unity-webview, but it works for android, not WebGL.
Also, I tried IFrame tag in index.html file.  It works differently than what I require.
Please help,
Thank you

Why? Why would you want to have a webpage on which you show a 3D Unity content and then within that 3D content again show a webpage? You already are in WebGL meaning you already have an HTML page around your Unity 3D stuff ... just show the webpage directly in the HTML (e.g. as iframe) JavaScript side - it works different than what I require - well what exactly do you require?

I am working on 2D not 3D , Specially this app is made to show results of Lotto , a casino game. So We are showing three screens one after one within 60 Sec timeDifference, Currently i am having two screens to show , these screens are UI Panels, now we want to add one new panel in which we have to show content of a URL(from API response), Means in UI Image or Raw image we have to open a site?

So why go for Unity at all then? tbh sounds a bit overkill to throw a complete 3D game engine on a 2D UI only use case ... I'd still claim it would be way easier and more efficient to solve this HTML/JavaScript side right away ... imho even your current panels should probably go there but that's another story ...

for the third screen you could simply make the Unity iFrame invisible via JavaScript (CSS) and enable another iFrame that contains the mentioned URL content .. you can have a simple Plugin if you insist sticking to Unity for that

Thanks @derHugo , Problem solved by using JavaScript , I created Plugin and displayed contents by assigning dynamic url to java script's function. All works well as expected.

Hello all, this is github link for free UnityWebView with WebGL, works on full screen mode too:                                                  https://github.com/RishviRuchi/UnityWebView.git

Hey thanks for letting us know and sharing, that's the spirit! ;) Happy you could find a solution that works for you (and potentially others). It would be awesome if you could post this again as a proper answer to your own question so that other visitors of this post can find and appreciate it is as well

Problem solved by using JavaScript , I created Plugin and displayed contents by assigning dynamic url to java script's function. All works well as expected.
this is github link for free UnityWebView with WebGL, works on full screen mode too: https://github.com/RishviRuchi/UnityWebView
